# Make a GUI program to communicate with microcontroller via serial link

Tags: java, serial-port, html, communication, microcontroller

I want to connect my PIC micro controller to computer via serial link and control it. The MCU will send a series of bits, my program should extract useful information, so basically i should be able to work on individual bytes of received data and send some commands back.  So where should i begin to write such a program ?. I have worked on C programs and simple java programs and i know bit of PHP.

It will be much better if i can make it more like a webpage so that i can host a page on my computer which can be accessed by all devices in the network and control the mcu.

Please suggest me some ideas to implement the same

Comment: What do you have so far? Does your PIC have a serial port and do you know how to send data using it? Your question right now is quite broad.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would consider dealing with PIC or other microcontroller, because they are very low level hardware. There are some options like Arduino, RasberyPI, etc. They already have LAN or WiFi modules and cheap as well.

I would do it in a Service oriented way, so communicate via TCP/IP or UDP socket. In this way, you will have a standard interface. No mather what harware/software you have.

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about it:

1. write software to interface your micro-controller with your computer
2. the pc side of the interface is most likely written in c, so learn how to interface java and c with something like jni or jna
3. look into java ee to create a web server

It will be very broad and require a fair amount of work/learning.